# Customize eTrusted widget color already integrated in the footer

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, darkmode

I followed the guide at https://help.etrusted.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360044944492#where-can-i-browse-available-widgets and successfully integrated the eTrusted badge into the footer of my Shopify shop by copy-pasting the generated code:

```
<div class="footer__item-content">
   {%- if block.settings.content != blank -%}
   {{- block.settings.content -}}
   {%- endif -%}

   {%- render 'social-media' -%}

   <!-- Begin eTrusted bootstrap tag -->
   <script src="https://integrations.etrusted.com/applications/widget.js/v2" defer async></script>
   <!-- End eTrusted bootstrap tag -->

   <!-- Begin eTrusted widget tag -->
   <etrusted-widget data-etrusted-widget-id="MY_ID"></etrusted-widget>
   <!-- End eTrusted widget tag -->

</div>
```

However, I'm having trouble customizing the widget's color. I want the widget to be white because my webpage footer is black:

[image]

but I couldn't find a way to change it.

I also checked out another guide at https://help.etrusted.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360047497311-How-do-I-adapt-the-Trustbadge-to-my-require..., but it doesn't seem to affect the widget's user interface.

Does anyone know how to customize the eTrusted widget color? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!